# How to make Windows 10 recognize Earphone inline mic/controls?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone

I just recently bought a Samsung Earphones (3 mm one jack) with legit & working inline controls & mic, tho it only works on smartphones and tablets? **Is it possible to make it work on PC too?** Do I need drivers for that? 
[My headphones here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlBm7.png)

I'm just using the Generic Sound Drivers for Windows since my laptop is an Windows Vista era laptop and the audio drivers isn't fully compatible with Windows (such as SRS Premium Sound, Surround Sound settings, Equalizers) so I just uninstalled it.

**I was hoping too to also make my PC recognize other audio inputs when something is put on the jacks, and apply the separate volume level separate with my PC speaker?** Is that still possible for my PC? [This what my jacks look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfV8M.jpg)

**It will also be much generous of you if you can also even help me bring back that old and more audio improvements features on my audio drivers.** The SRS, Surround Sound and the Equalizer. It stopped working when I updated on Windows 8.1. It's working on Vista to 8.

Answer (score 1):

The standard audio outputs are output only. There is no hardware to receive the feedback. A headphone with a microphone built in has 4 channels where a normal plug has 3. Count the black bands on the plug. You will see either 2 black bands or 3.

There is only one audio input on most sound cards. If you need multiple audio inputs you will need another sound-card. I recommend one built for audio recording.

You can get cheap USB sound-cards if you don't need studio quality recordings.

Answer (score 0):

For the Headphones to work properly. You should use an adapter like this one :
[Jack Spliter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016LDZ36)

---

For the advanced functions to work (separate volumes etc..), you need to install compatible and proper drivers. The main issue here is that your OEM probably does not support anything past vista.

- A solution (aside from reinstalling your driver manually) that you
  may try is to install (manually) drivers from the **same OEM** and
  for the **same make** of Audio chipset via a little bit more recent
  **model**.

For instance :
if you have a Lenovo **T420**, try the Win 8.1 Audio drivers for Lenovo **T430** (I suppose that they both use for instance **Realtek** Audio chipsets).

- You can also try to see if your audio chipset vendor's website
  contain compatible drivers.

Comment: Let say after I did find another newer hardware's same driver that both works on Windows 10 and my PC, what should I do next to enable that separate volumes? You didn't specify that part on your answer. Tho Thanks for the answer

Comment: Well I can't guess what your specific OEM settings interface looks like :) A screenshot would help us handle this :)

Comment: OEM settings? What do you mean? The BIOS OEM settings? The audio driver settings shipped by the OEM? What settings? Please specify

Comment: settings of the 'ASUS'/'Lenovo' sound driver.

Comment: How about the mic jack? My laptop got three jacks, the splitter you linked on amazon just got two. Is there any splitter that got three?

Comment: Here's my PC software screenshot btw http://imgur.com/a/cRRkw Now can you help me more about this?

Comment: Settings or Preferences shall contain the settings..

Answer (score 0):

I've found the perfect solution. I've recently bought one of these too and it worked after these steps:

1. Search HD audio manager
2. Click the folder on top right.
3. Tick the box where it says to popup when new device plugged in
4. Reconnect your earphones
5. Now when popup select 'HEADSET'
6. Now you are ready, just test it in voice recorder app

Comment: This used to work for me - as recently as early 2020, I think. It isn't working anymore. I don't know if it has anything to do with having installed Creative drivers for a USB sound card.